# Copy Text from a <Span> without identifying ID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

how can I do it so when a user clicks a  html tag it copies the text to the user's clipboard. I also need to do it so I don't make it work for a certain tag id/name as I cant add those to my span. How can I auto attach it to the span that was clicked?

I tried many methods but it seems only JQuery can do this as regular JS cant just attach to the element it was clicked, it must be handed the ID/Name

Thank you!

Comment: jQuery-only doesn't exist, it's written with vanilla JS. It looks like you need to add a click listener to `document`, and then check the clicked target from the event object.

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to make an attempt and show your code so we have something to talk about.

Comment: @Teemu I did not know that thanks for explaining this!

Comment: @isherwood I google d a lot and there is no info on my specific question and I did not know enough to start without some guidance. Sorry..

Comment: You're asking multiple questions here and not providing details for any of them: How to select an element other than by class/ID, how to copy to clipboard, how to handle click events. All that's been widely covered already. This is why you need to be more _specific_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('body').on('click', 'span', function() {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(this).text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
});
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>sdasdfdsf</span>
</body>
</html>
```